# Get union of keys of all objects in js array using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, functional-programming

Assume , we have :

```
var all=[
    {firstname:'Ahmed', age:12},
    {firstname:'Saleh', children:5 }
    {fullname: 'Xod BOD', children: 1}
];
```

The expected result is `['firstname','age', 'children', 'fullname']`: the union of keys of all objects of that array:

```
all.map((e) => Object.keys(e) ).reduce((a,b)=>[...a,...b],[]);
```

This is work fine , However, i am seeking a solution more performance using directly `reduce` method without `map` , I did the following and it is failed.

```
all.reduce((a,b) =>Object.assign([...Object.keys(a),...Object.keys(b)]),[])
```

Comment: Probably better posted on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) but `Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...all))` is one option. I have no idea about performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Set`, `reduce()` and `Object.keys()` there is no need for map.

```js
var all=[
  {firstname:'Ahmed', age:12},
  {firstname:'Saleh', children:5 },
  {fullname: 'Xod BOD', children: 1}
];

var result = [...new Set(all.reduce((r, e) => [...r, ...Object.keys(e)], []))];
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why the `Set`? Your `all.reduce((r, e) => r.concat(Object.keys(e)), [])` already gives an Array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using generic procedures `concat`, `flatMap`, and the ES6 `Set`.

It's similar to @NenadVracar's solution but uses higher-order functions  instead of a complex, do-it-all-in-one-line implementation. This reduces complexity in your transformation and makes it easier to re-use procedures in other areas of your program.

Not that `...` spread syntax is bad, but you'll also notice this solution does not necessitate it.

```js
var all = [
  {firstname:'Ahmed', age:12},
  {firstname:'Saleh', children:5 },
  {fullname: 'Xod BOD', children: 1}
];

const concat = (x,y) => x.concat(y);

const flatMap = f => xs => xs.map(f).reduce(concat, []);

const unionKeys = xs =>
  Array.from(new Set(flatMap (Object.keys) (xs)));

console.log(unionKeys(all));
// [ 'firstname', 'age', 'children', 'fullname' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var union = new Set(getKeys(all));

console.log(union);
// if you need it to be array
console.log(Array.from(union));

//returns the keys of the objects inside the collection
function getKeys(collection) {
    return collection.reduce(
        function(union, current) {
            if(!(union instanceof Array)) {
                union = Object.keys(union);
            }
            return union.concat(Object.keys(current));
        });
}
```

Comment: It's a valiant effort but `addToSet` mutates `set` which is generally ill-advised in functional programs.

Comment: @naomik What do you mean by "mutates `set`"? `set` is only a variable here.

Comment: @naomik Why would this be a bad thing to do in this particular case?

Comment: a goal of functional programming is to create pure functions – mutations should be localized in a way that allows your functions to run without producing side effects.

Comment: @naomik Thank you for the remark, check my edit, I tried to remove this flaw (:

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, I've been benchmarking some solutions to your problem using different approaches (reduce vs foreach vs set). Looks like Set behaves well for small arrays but it's extremely slow for bigger arrays (being the best solution the foreach one).

Hope it helps.

```js
var all = [{
    firstname: 'Ahmed',
    age: 12
  }, {
    firstname: 'Saleh',
    children: 5
  }, {
    fullname: 'Xod BOD',
    children: 1
  }],
  result,
  res = {};

const concat = (x,y) => x.concat(y);

const flatMap = f => xs => xs.map(f).reduce(concat, []);

const unionKeys = xs =>
  Array.from(new Set(flatMap (Object.keys) (xs)));

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  all = all.concat(all);

console.time("Reduce");
result = Object.keys(all.reduce((memo, obj) => Object.assign(memo, obj), {}));
console.timeEnd("Reduce");

console.time("foreach");
all.forEach(obj => Object.assign(res, obj));
result = Object.keys(res);
console.timeEnd("foreach");

console.time("Set");
result = [...new Set(all.reduce((r, e) => r.concat(Object.keys(e)), []))];
console.timeEnd("Set");

console.time("Set2");
result = unionKeys(all);
console.timeEnd("Set2");
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `{}` as a memo. Use `Set` or `Map` for this kind of thing.

Comment: @naomik As you can read in the post, I was testing the performance of some implementations and one of them uses Set

Comment: you didn't use `Set` as a memo tho, so your comparison is almost completely meaningless. `Set` was only used to remove non-unique values from the result.